# background colour for active link in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, hyperlink, routes, html-lists

I have been working on styling part for my React application sidebar.

What I have is a list of items and each will route to a different page.

So, now I want to check on which route I'm on by having the link active but I had a problem and can find solution.

Can you help me put with this. I have given my code below. I want to have the background color for the link I'm active on.

CODE:

Dashboard.js

```
            <div>
             <ul>
              <Link to="/homepage">Dashboard</Link>
              <Link to="/customers">Customers</Link>
              <Link to="/products">Products</Link>
              <Link to="/orders">Orders</Link>
              <Link to="/analytics">Analytics</Link>
              <Link to="/categories">Categories</Link>
              <Link to="/discount">Discount</Link>
              <Link to="/inventory">Inventory</Link>
              <Link to="/settings">Settings</Link>
             </ul>
            </div>
```

Dashboard.css

```
ul{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    box-shadow: rgba(149, 157, 165, 0.2) 0px 8px 24px;
}

ul a {
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

ul a:active {
    background-color: #349eff;
}

ul a:hover{
    background-color: #349eff;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If activeStyle doesn't work for You, I think that's because You must be in react-router-dom V6.

In V6 I use a little tip :

```
const Menu = () => {
    const {pathname} = useLocation();

    return (
        <ul>
            <ul>
              <Link className={(pathname === '/homepage') ? 'active' : ''} to="/homepage">Dashboard</Link>
              <Link className={(pathname === '/customers') ? 'active' : ''} to="/customers">Customers</Link>
              <Link className={(pathname === '/products') ? 'active' : ''} to="/products">Products</Link>
              <Link className={(pathname === '/orders') ? 'active' : ''} to="/orders">Orders</Link>
              <Link className={(pathname === '/analytics') ? 'active' : ''} to="/analytics">Analytics</Link>
              <Link className={(pathname === '/categories') ? 'active' : ''} to="/categories">Categories</Link>
              <Link className={(pathname === '/discount') ? 'active' : ''} to="/discount">Discount</Link>
              <Link className={(pathname === '/inventory') ? 'active' : ''} to="/inventory">Inventory</Link>
              <Link className={(pathname === '/settings') ? 'active' : ''} to="/settings">Settings</Link>
             </ul>
        </ul>
    )

}
```

So, as You can see, I use pathname to get location. And in className I use a ternary function to apply active class or not.
If You also use a class for each Link, you could do :

```
className={`menu_item ${(pathname === '/') ? 'active' : ''}`}
```

In this case Your Link will have "menu_item" as class and if it's active "menu_item active".

In the documentation, they use a different way, but I think it's more simple like that.

Edit: I forgot to point out that in Your css You must use "ul a.active" instead of "ul a:active"

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "activeStyle" attribute to link elements like this:

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <Link activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: #349eff; }} to="/homepage">Dashboard</Link>
  <Link activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: #349eff; }} to="/customers">Customers</Link>
  <Link activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: #349eff; }} to="/products">Products</Link>
  <Link activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: #349eff; }} to="/orders">Orders</Link>
  <Link activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: #349eff; }} to="/analytics">Analytics</Link>
  <Link activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: #349eff; }} to="/categories">Categories</Link>
  <Link activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: #349eff; }} to="/discount">Discount</Link>
  <Link activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: #349eff; }} to="/inventory">Inventory</Link>
  <Link activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: #349eff; }} to="/settings">Settings</Link>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: No activeStyle is not working at all

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution would be styling the link directly from your react file rather than from your css file like so:

```
<Link to="first" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
  <MenuItem style={{ paddingLeft: 13 }}>Team 1</MenuItem>
</Link>
```

For more information on react links and overall styling in React view this article https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/react+link+remove+underline+and+change+color

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using activeStyle I have used `activeClassName="active-link"` and I am now able to style it using the `className="active-link"` in css file and it worked.

Hope this might help if above solutions don't work as in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **NavLink**. Import it like:

> `import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";`

Then, you can use the **isActive** in you **NavLink** to set active link styling!

> `<NavLink className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "link-active" : "none")} to='/'> Text </NavLink>`

**"link-active"** is a class you can put your styles (using CSS) and **"none"** is a class you can style for when the link is inactive.

Answer (score -1):

```
       <div>
         <ul>
          <Link activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: 
           window.location.href.includes('homepage') ? "#349eff" :"" }} 
           to="/homepage">Dashboard</Link>
          <Link activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: 
           window.location.href.includes('customers') ? "#349eff" :"" }}  
            to="/customers">Customers</Link>
          <Link  activeStyle={{ backgroundColor: 
           window.location.href.includes('products') ? "#349eff" :"" }}  
            to="/products">Products</Link>
         </ul>
        </div>
```